# Remove [micro-sd-card] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

This tag is redundant, as [sd-card] exists. There aren't many things specific to micro SD cards that aren't shared traits with SD cards.

Comment: You're right about the similarity, but just a thought.  Sometimes we use synonyms or even multiple tags so someone can easily find a tag that matches how they are thinking about their problem or searching for a solution.  Do you have any thoughts on whether there might be any value along those lines lost if we eliminate the tag?  Any thoughts on retagging and eliminating this one vs. making it a synonym of the [sd-card] tag?  (in that case, either tag name would work for finding a tag or searching, but only the primary would actually appear on the question.)

Comment: @fixer1234 Now that you mention it, making it a synonym might be a better idea.

Comment: There isn't a generic tag, like [data-card], and one probably wouldn't be useful because it isn't what pops to mind when you're thinking about SD or micro-SD.  Given that the tags are form-factor specific, there's value in seeing the "right" tag; less confusing.  OTOH, there would be benefit in linking these together so answers posted under one form-factor are readily available under the other.  I'm not aware of a way to keep both tags available for attachment, but link them for searching.  A synonym might be next best, with explanation in the wiki excerpt (even though people don't read them).

Answer (score 2):

*People may not have responded to the question due to the solution presented in the question not being seen as desirable, even if some type of action seems warranted.  I'll post an answer to bump the issue with another solution people can react to.*

---

There is a trade-off here.

- It is helpful to have separate tags consistent with the terms people use to think about their problem.
- Aside from that, the only practical difference between the form-factors that would affect answers here is the lack of a locking switch on the micro-SD format.  Keeping the two tags separate hides useful solutions on the other tag, or encourages people to double tag.

Synonyms are the mechanism available for linking multiple intuitive tags to the same content.  SD Card is the more generic term.  **Let's make [micro-sd-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/micro-sd-card) a synonym of [sd-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sd-card)**, and expand the wiki and excerpt to clarify that the tag applies to both formats.

For that matter, we could probably make it even more generic and make it applicable to any form-factor of a generally similar flash memory card (comment on preferences regarding this last point).